# DataTables plugin using jQuery to add a column in the table of a button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTablesPlugin but I want to add a column with buttons and another that has a link.

I try to make the button as follows:

```
var eliminar = document.createElement ('button')

eliminar.type = 'button';

var imagen = document.createElement ('img');

imagen.src = 'prueba.png';

eliminar.appendChild (imagen);

  $ ('# example'). dataTable (). fnAddData ([
number,
name,
address,
eliminar
]);
```

BUT MAKE THE FOLLOWING ERROR:

[object HTMLButtonElement]

The variables number, name, and address if shown in the table that are strings and were taken from a json.

I have read http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/html_sort.html but do not quite understand.

Could anyone help me solve this?
Thanks and sorry I am new to java script and jquery,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help with your problem, but there are two sytax problems I can see with your code:

```
var eliminar = document.createElement ('button')
```

is missing a semicolon at the end.

```
$ ('# example'). dataTable (). fnAddData ([
```

has spaces where no spaces should be.

```
$ ('#example').dataTable().fnAddData ([
```

The space character is not valid in IDs JavaScript. If your table actually has an ID with a leading space, you should delete that.